# Is it possible to extract text from handwritten notes in OneNote?

Tags: onenote, handwriting-recognition, digital-handwritting

For a project I am looking for ways to extract text from handwritten notes in OneNote. The idea is that one can quickly write notes in OneNote and then my application reads the notes and saves it as a text file somewhere else.

I have read into the REST API and I know that there are many ways to submit content to OneNote, but I am not sure about extracting handwritten ("ink" ?) content from it.

Answer (score 1):

The OneNote apps across multiple platforms have varying degrees of ability to analyze ink strokes and recognize text. For e.g. in the Windows Desktop app, [you can convert handwriting to text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Take-notes-in-your-own-handwriting-46fe3ab9-5747-4820-b646-0c08935c5991).

But the extracted text is not supported by the REST APIs today.

Comment: I didn't find the "ink to text" button. It seems to be a popular problem for OneNote on iPad